# How to add multiple videos in one page using Screencast Video Embedder?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress.I want to know how can I use multiple screencast  videos in a single page using "Screencast Video Embedder" plugin.

Please help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this [Screencast.com Video Embedder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/screencastcom-video-embedder/).

It Looks like the plugin uses shortcodes `[screencast url="SCREENCAST SHORT URL" width="WIDTH" height="HEIGHT"]` so just add that multiple times to your page with different screencast urls.

Comment: Hi, Is there any plugin for word press which can open multiple videos(each for separate link) in popup style? Thanks

Comment: take a look at this [plugin here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cool-video-gallery/screenshots/)

Comment: Hi, do we have some video plugin for WordPress So that we can host our videos on some other site like screencast.com and access than on a single page and open in popup style.

Comment: I do not know, im sure you can make one though using the above listed plugin in my answer

Comment: Hi I tried cool video gallery.But could you please guide me how can I find the video Id.I wan to use this "[cvg-video videoId='vid' /]"